# Reading in a list of files into a list of DataFrames

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to read a list of files into a list of Pandas DataFrames in Python. However, the code below doesn't work.

```
files = [file1, file2, file3]

df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df3 = pd.DataFrame()

dfs = [df1, df2, df3]

# Read in data files
for file,df in zip(files, dfs):
    if file_exists(file):
        with open(file, 'rb') as in_file:
            df = pd.read_csv(in_file, low_memory=False)
            print df        #the file is getting read properly

print df1    #empty
print df2    #empty
print df3    #empty
```

How to I get the original DataFrames to update if I pass them into a for-loop as a list of DataFrames?

Comment: what is your goal to read those files into three DFs or to merge them together into single DF?

Comment: You're updating the iterable rather than what the element is, it would be the same thing if you iterated over a list. Is there a reason you need to construct the empty dfs upfront rather than just set `dfs=[]` and then just iterate over the files and do `dfs.append(pd.read_csv(in_file)`?

Comment: When you iterate over a list, you can't modify the element directly. The line `df = pd.read_csv(in_file, low_memory=False)` is not actually modifying the elements in the list, it's modifying a copy of the element. EDIT: beat me to it @EdChum :)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python for an explanation, but essentially you can just skip this and just append to a list your created dfs

Comment: @MaxU: I was trying to read files into three different DFs. The idea was that by using a loop, one could concisely import any number of files.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, low_memory=False) for f in files]
```

if you want to check whether file exists:

```
import os

dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, low_memory=False) for f in files if os.path.isfile(f)]
```

and if you want to concatenate all of them into one data frame:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, low_memory=False)
                for f in files if os.path.isfile(f)],
               ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not working on the list elements themselves when iterating over them but you are **not** operating on the list.

You need to insert the elements (or append them) to the list. One possibility could be:

```
files = [file1, file2, file3]

dfs = [None] * 3 # Just a placeholder

# Read in data files
for i, file in enumerate(files): # Enumeration instead of zip
    if file_exists(file):
        with open(file, 'rb') as in_file:
            dfs[i] = pd.read_csv(in_file, low_memory=False) # Setting the list element
            print dfs[i]      #the file is getting read properly
```

This updates the list elements and should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems over complicated you can just do:

```
files = [file1, file2, file3]

dfs = []

# Read in data files
for file in files:
    if file_exists(file):
        dfs.append(pd.read_csv(file, low_memory=False))
```

You will end up with a list of dfs as desired

Answer (score 0):

You can try `list` comprehension:

```
files = [file1, file2, file3]

dfs = [pd.read_csv(x, low_memory=False) for x in files if file_exists(x)]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Custom-written Python function that appropriately handles both CSV & JSON files.

```
def generate_list_of_dfs(incoming_files):
    """
    Accepts a list of csv and json file/path names.
    Returns a list of DataFrames.
    """
    outgoing_files = []
    for filename in incoming_files:
        file_extension = filename.split('.')[1]
        if file_extension == 'json':
            with open(filename, mode='r') as incoming_file:
                outgoing_json = pd.DataFrame(json.load(incoming_file))
                outgoing_files.append(outgoing_json)
        if file_extension == 'csv':
            outgoing_csv = pd.read_csv(filename)
            outgoing_files.append(outgoing_csv)
    return outgoing_files
```

## How to Call this Function

```
import pandas as pd
import json    
files_to_be_read = ['filename1.json', 'filename2.csv', 'filename3.json', 'filename4.csv']
dataframes_list = generate_list_of_dfs(files_to_be_read)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution that avoids using a list to hold all the data frames, if you don't need them in a list.

```
import fnmatch

# get the CSV files only
files = fnmatch.filter(os.listdir('.'), '*.csv')
files
```

Output which is now a list of the names:

```
['Feedback Form Submissions 1.21-1.25.22.csv',
 'Feedback Form Submissions 1.21.22.csv',
 'Feedback Form Submissions 1.25-1.31.22.csv']
```

Now create a simple list of new names to make working with them easier:

```
# use a simple format
names = []
for i in range(0,len(files)):
    names.append('data' + str(i))
names

['data0', 'data1', 'data2']
```

You can use any list of names that you want.  The next step take the file names and the list of names and then assign them to the names.

```
# i is the incrementor for the list of names
i = 0

# iterate through the file names
for file in files:
    # make an empty dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    # load the first file in
    df = pd.read_csv(file, low_memory=False)
    # get the first name from the list, this will be a string
    new_name = names[i]
    # assign the string to the variable and assign it to the dataframe 
    locals()[new_name] = df.copy()
    # increment the list of names
    i = i + 1
```

You now have 3 separate dataframes named data0, data1, data2, and do commands like

```
data2.info()
```